# How to use single letters to form words

Tags: c++

Hey I currently have this code. It gets the user to input strings into an array, with a limit of 5. I plan to use the array to then form words from the array. How can I achieve this?

```
    const int row = 5;
    char array[row];
    char count = 0;
    char letter;
    while (count < 5)
    {
        cout << "Enter a letter: ";
        cin >> letter;
        array[count] = letter;
        count++;
    }
    cout << "Letter inputed" << endl;
    for (count = 0; count < 5; count++)
    {
        cout << array[count] << " " <<  endl;
    }
    system("pause");
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have a dictionary of legal words to check against?

Comment: Do you mean meaningful words or permutations of those letters?

Comment: meaningful words, but I guess an example of permutation would be a good example

Comment: So how is the program supposed to know whether a sequence of letters is an English (or whatever language you are working in) word?

Comment: But you're inputting chars, not strings.

Comment: Getting permutations and getting meaningful words are two totally different problems. Sample code doing one thing does not help one bit with the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses an associative array to map from sorted letters of the word to the words having such sorted letters. It's thus possible to get an answer with one lookup in the map, which takes asymptotically `O(log N)` time, where N is a size of your dictionary.

Create a file named `dic.txt`. In case you're using `Visual Studio` it should be in the same directory as your `*.cpp` files. Put several words inside in a "word in a row" format. Try the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // Dictionary file is in a "word in a row" format
    map< string, vector<string> > dictionary;
    ifstream dictionary_file("dic.txt");
    if (!dictionary_file.good()) {
        cout << "File doesn't exist" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    string word;
    while (dictionary_file >> word) {
        string key = word;
        sort(key.begin(), key.end());
        dictionary[key].push_back(word);
    }

    // Read the letters
    string letters;
    cin >> letters;
    if (letters.size() > 5) {
        cout << "Too much letters" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    // Sort the letters
    sort(letters.begin(), letters.end());

    // Output the answers
    vector<string> & ret = dictionary[letters];
    for (size_t i = 0, ilen = ret.size(); i < ilen; ++i) {
        cout << ret[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Mention that such a solution cares for a case your letters are in. In case you don't need it, you can add calls to `strtolower` function (got that name from PHP) before you add a word to your dictionary and before you sort your letters.

```
string strtolowers(string const & word) {
    string ret = word;
    transform(ret.begin(), ret.end(), ret.begin(), tolower);
    return ret;
}
```

You'll need to add `<cctype>` header for this function to work.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Don't have a single idea why I did it in that way. (Also found a typo.) Thank you.

Comment: @user2881555 It's waiting for your input. In case you need a message like `Letters, please!` you're free to add it yourself, but this is not considered a good programming practice.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph Hmm when i run it, and i input let say `a` it closes the program

Comment: @user2881555 If you're using Visual Studio 2008 or less, you can run program with Ctrl-F5 key to prevent if from immediate exit at finish. In case you're on Windows, and you want your program to always wait for user input at exit, add `system("pause")` as the last line of `int main()` and `<cstdlib>` header to the top. Can't help very much in case you're using *nix.

Comment: Well its not exiting, but it's outputting `Press any key to continue . . .` when i input only 1 letter.

Comment: Did you fill your `dic.txt` file and placed it in a right folder? Does that letter exist in that `dic.txt` file?

Comment: Its in the correct folder, as its opening it, do I add a word each line in the text file?

Comment: @user2881555 Sure it should contain some words. How would the program test if the word is a correct, if it doesn't have a word list? You can get one from `http://wordlist.sourceforge.net/`, for example the one called `Ispell English Word Lists`. Rename, for example, `english.0` file into `dic.txt`.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph Downloaded it, added it still not working.. What am i meant to input for it to correctly work

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39934/discussion-between-polkovnikov-ph-and-user2881555)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a hint to get you started on the right track: don't even *consider* using `std::next_permutation` unless this is something you'll only ever use once or twice (and probably not even then, because it's actually more complicated than doing the job right).

Using `std::next_permutation`, your function will be approximately N! times slower than necessary<sup>1</sup> -- in the case of 5 letters, that'll be 120 times slower, and if you ever use longer words, it'll get worse *very* quickly (e.g., for 10 letters it's over 3.5 million).

Instead, start by pre-processing your dictionary. Instead of a `std::set<std::string>` of words, create an `std::map<std::string, std::vector<string>>` (or `std::unordered_map`, though English has few enough words that this probably won't make a huge difference). As you read in a word from the dictionary, create a sorted version of that string. Use that as the key, and push the original version of the word onto the vector for that key.

Then when you get a word from the user, sort it, look that up in the map, and the associated vector will contain every word (from your dictionary) that can be created from those letters.

---

<sub>1. If you use `std::map` instead of `std::unordered_map`, that should be something like `N!/(log N)`, but `N!` grows so fast and `log N` grows so slowly that it the difference is negligible (if you get N large enough that log N = 3, N! will be so large that N!/log N computation steps...well, you start to get into questions of cosmology, like whether the universe will have died of heat death before then (to which the answer seems to be "yes, probably").</sub>

Comment: Fixed my answer to implement this technique. Not pretty sure topicstarter wants to dive in a complexity theory, though.

Comment: @Jarod42: I've never heard of a name specifically for it, though it probably deserves one--it's not immediately obvious, and (under the right circumstances) it's *tremendously* useful.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hint to get you started. There's a function in the standard library called `std::next_permutation`. Assuming you have a dictionary of words to check against, a possible solution could look like this:

```
std::sort(array, array + row);
do {
    // Check if array is a word.
} while (std::next_permutation(array, array + row));
```

This will cycle through every permutation of letters. It's now up to you to verify that it is a valid word.

Comment: Also array should be sorted lexographically initially to get all permutations

Comment: That should be `array + (row - 1)`, otherwise you're also moving `\0`.

Comment: It's not a string, it's an array of characters. He's never putting a `\0` in there.

Comment: The complexity will be `O(row! * #dict)` (`5! == 120`).

Comment: Of course. But like I said this is a "hint" to get him started.

Comment: Also, if you use a trie structure, then you can cut the complexity down to about `O(row! * row)`.

Comment: @bstamour Actually, it can be done in `O(1)` time, if one is using `unordered_map<string, string>` from sorted dictionary words to original ones. I'm not pretty sure topicstarter asks for this.

Comment: And that's why I omitted details. The topic starter asked to see an example involving permutations, and that's what I gave.